# Initialisation of C++ structures from C

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv `C++` library with another lib in `C`. So I've defined a structure in an `.hpp` file which I've added to the `.h` of the `C` library

```
typedef struct {
  cv::FileStorage fs;
  cv::Mat mat;
} myCPPStruct;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {    
    myCPPStruct * mycppstruct;    
} myCStruct;

void initialize_myCPPStruct(myCPPStruct * mycppstruct);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In the `.c` files the initializer for myCStruct calls `initialize_myCPPStruct` which is defined in a `.cpp` file somewhat as:

```
void initialize_myCPPStruct(myCPPStruct * mycppstruct){
  mycppstruct = {};
  mycppstruct->fs = cv::FileStorage( "file.txt", cv::FileStorage::READ );
  mycppstruct->mat = cv::Mat(3,3,CV_8UC3);
}
```

But once it tries to allocate a value to `mycppstruct->fs`, it gets a segmentation fault. I assume this is because there is no memory allocation in C, but I've tried

`std::memset(stitcher->fs,0,sizeof(cv::FileStorage));`

which also doesn't work as it can't parse `cv:FileStorage` as `void *`.

Will I have to use the deprecated C OpenCV library to make this work?

EDIT - More details about the compilation.

For the `C` lib, I recompile (without linking ie with the `-c` option)all the `.c`  files where I've added `C++` functions or structures using `g++` while making sure I add the `__cplusplus` guards in the `.h` files. All the `.c` files without `C++` code already have `.o` files compiled with `gcc`. I then compile the whole program with `g++` while making sure to include the relevant library files. There are no compiler errors.

Comment: How do you expect your C compiler to process C++ code?

Comment: @Torbjörn Um, compile without linking with g++? The issue here is not compiling

Comment: @Torbjörn Why the downvote? The question is not a compiler issue

Comment: Just for record: I did not down vote. Back to topic: You did not say how you actually do the link between the C++ library and your C code. That might help.

Comment: Apologies, I assumed you downvoted since you are the only that answered.  I compile all the `c` which include `c++` functions or structures using `g++` while making sure i add the `__cplusplus` guards in the headers. All the `c` files without `c++` code already have `.o` files compiled with `gcc`. I then compile the whole program with `g++` while making sure to include the relevant library files.

Comment: You should add that to your question. This info seems crucial.

Comment: @Torbjörn, good idea. I've just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the structure itself has not been created.
You might try this (or something similar):

```
myCPPStruct* initialize_myCPPStruct()
{
  myCPPStruct* result;
  result = new myCPPStruct();
  result->fs = cv::FileStorage( "file.txt", cv::FileStorage::READ );
  result->mat = cv::Mat(3,3,CV_8UC3);
  return (result);
}
```

Comment: Yup, it was simply the matter of initialising the myCPPStruct with `new myCPPStruct()` Which is strange because I thought I had actually tried that. Also I refactored my function to work as yours, as in that it simply returns the initialized structure, without the structure being passed to the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me point out the sentence which confuse me.

> there is no memory allocation in C

Yes, there is. Have a look to `malloc` function.

```
char *my_allocated_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 42);
```

Here you are, you've allocated an array of character of size 42.

Now, have a look to : `mycppstruct = {};`

That's not how you allocate a structure in C. You have to call... `malloc()` !

```
my_struct *s = malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
s->fs = 42;
```

Ok. Done. Feels better.

---

Well, first of all, you have to create a wrapper around your C++ code. Why ? Because C++ allows multiple definition of a given function (also call *symbol*) :

```
int my_func(int);
int my_func(char);
```

This is valid in C++. But, think about it, how is the compiler able to let two functions with the same name exist ? Well it's not. It uses a technique named [*mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) when evaluating the functions to create 2 different names. Mangling is use on everything function and method. Event on single functions.

C is not able (and willing) to create several functions with the same name. Otherwise, you will experience a kind of *function-already-implemented* error. When you declare :

```
int my_func(int);
```

the C compiler will create the symbol : `my_func`. No mangling.

To make both language interact, you need to reference to a symbol understandable by the C compiler. If you call `my_func` from a C source file, the C compiler will look for `my_func` symbol. Bu since C++ will modify its `my_func` symbol into something like `_ZN9myfuncE`, the linkage will fail. That's why you have to says to the C++ compiler to **not** use mangling on the function you expose to C. That's why you need `extern "C" { }`.

Feeww, so far so good...

Now you have to embed you C API into an `extern "C"` block :

In `my_c_api.h` :

```
void my_func(int);
void my_func(char);
```

In `my_c_api.cpp` :

```
#include "my_c_api.h"

extern "C" void my_func_i(int i) { my_func(i); }
extern "C" void my_func_c(char c) { my_func(c); }
```

You compile it to create your C++ library.

In your C compilation pipeline, you link against your new C++ library and header files. Then :

```
#include "<path_to_my_c_api.h>"

void c(int i,char s)
{
    my_func_i(i);
    my_func_c(c);
}
```

You cannot compile C++ code with C compiler. You have to compile te C++ code independently.

[More on ISO CPP.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp)

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate the memory for your structure:

```
    myCPPStruct = malloc(sizeof(myCPPStruct));
```

Use the above line instead of:

```
    mycppstruct = {};
```

Also,since your function is passing in the pointer and allocating the memory internally you need to pass a pointer to the pointer or the allocation will not be passed back:

```
    void initialize_myCPPStruct(myCPPStruct** mycppstruct){
        if ( mycppstruct == NULL ) {
     //Abort as no address of the pointer to allocate passed
            return;
        }
        *myCPPStruct = malloc(sizeof(myCPPStruct));
        (*mycppstruct)->fs = cv::FileStorage( "file.txt", cv::FileStorage::READ );
        (*mycppstruct)->mat = cv::Mat(3,3,CV_8UC3);
    }
```

Or you could just change the above to:

```
    myCPPStruct* initialize_myCPPStruct(void) {
        myCPPStruct* ptr = malloc(sizeof(myCPPStruct));
        ptr->fs = cv::FileStorage( "file.txt", cv::FileStorage::READ );
        ptr->mat = cv::Mat(3,3,CV_8UC3);
        return ptr;
    }
```